# How to find why a Java 8 app is not defaulting to TLSv1.2?

Tags: java, tls1.2

I am looking an app (that's already developed) which is used to make REST API calls to a service. This is resulting in fatal error which when debugged used tcpdump showed that the requests were using TLSv1.0 where as the service is expecting v1.2.
This app is running on Java 8 and as per the jre docs, in Java 8 TLS is supposed to be defaulting to TLSv1.2.

Why is the app not sending requests using TLSv1.2 and how do I go about debugging it? Should I just pass https.protocol options in the java arguments?

Thanks!
PS: I am pretty new to Java.

Comment: what version of the JDK are you running on?

Comment: System property `https.protocols` (with `s` or it's ignored) can be set on commandline or in code but only affects connections using `HttpsURLConnection` or in some cases Apache httpclient; is that what your code does? For all code methods `jdk.tls.client.protocols` _may_ be used as a default.

Comment: @OldProgrammer JDK 1.8.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Why is the default of 1.2 not used even though it is a JDK 1.8 app?

Comment: Could be the application or a library you use, other code, the JVM configuration or environment. There are probably thousdands of possibilities depending on info you didn't give. Find a [minimal example that shows the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and if you don't find the problem while doing so, add to your Q. A starting point might be a class containing only `SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(yourhost,yourport);` `System.out.println (Arrays.toString (s.getEnabledProtocols()));` `s.startHandshake();`

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the TLS handshake by adding the **javax.net.debug** parameter:

```
java  -Djavax.net.debug=all -jar yourapp.jar
```

as suggested in [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: That will show/confirm what handshake is done (or attempted), but not what in the code or config caused it.

Comment: I see that the app is using TLSv1.0 with the help of tcpdump but why is it not defaulting to 1.2 is the question

Comment: Following the log trace can help you determine which party (client or server) is falling back to TLS 1.0, and why.